# Remove keys from two-dimensional array

Tags: key

I am dealing with a challenge that I have not found an answer here yet. I have a two-dimensional array like this:

```
myArray = (
   [0] = array (...),
   [1] = array (...),
   [2] = array (...)
);
```

I want to remove the keys so that I get:

```
myArray = (
   array (...),
   array (...),
   array (...)
);
```

Is there any way to do that in PHP?

Thanks and best regards,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried array_values() ? Should get rid of keys. 
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php
( BTW your array already looks like keyless )

Comment: Hi elshan,
thanks for your answer. I actually tried that but whenever I create a new array with the array_values, the new array is numerically indexed as well.

Some more info to my problem: I read from the database in a function. For each row found I add the row to an array which is then returned to the main routine. When I print_r that returned arry there I get this layout:

Comment: Array ( Array ( [firstname] => 'john', [lastname] => 'doe', ...), Array ( [firstname] => 'jane', ... ))

When I build the same array manually in the main routine I get this:

    Array ( [0] => Array ( [firstname] => 'john', ... ))

The array coming back from the database function I can process with:

    foreach( $records as $rec ) {
       $var = $rec['firstname'];
    }

For the second array I have to use this:

    foreach( $records as $rec ){
       $var = $rec[0]['firstname'];
    }

Meanwhile I found a different way to work around that but it still beats me.

Comment: Don't be confused by numeric indexes. In php if you do print_r( array( 'apple','banana','pear') ); you always get Array ( [0] => apple [1] => banana [2] => pear )